# How to fetch the post according to custom taxonomy, start date and end date with search input in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Custom post type --- **Event**

custom taxonomy----- **myevents**

Using jQuery Datepicker for Start date and End date

Search field for searching event name

[image]

I want to fetch the custom post type events by using the simple form search. In which I fetched custom taxonomy in select option, then I added start and end date using jQuery Datepicker at last Search field.

My search URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost/customthemedev/?categoryfilter=Techfest&Start=01-May-2019&End=10-May-2019&search=smoke+event+
```

```html
<form class="select-event-date" method="GET" action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>" autocomplete="off" id="filter">
  <div class="form-group eventfunction">
    <label>Categories</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="categoryfilter">
    <?php
       $tax_terms = get_terms('myevents', array('hide_empty' => '0'));      
       foreach ( $tax_terms as $tax_term ):
          echo '<option value="'.$tax_term->name.'">'.$tax_term->name.'</option>';   
       endforeach;
    ?>
    </select> 
  </div>
  <div class="form-group selectDate">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Start Date" name="Start" id="txtFrom">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group endDate">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="End Date" name="End"  id="txtTo">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group searchEvent">
    <label>
      <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();; ?>/assets/images/search-22.png" alt="Icon">
    </label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">FIND EVENTS</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this :
```

//Get all terms in array format

```
    $termSlug = array();
    $tax_terms = get_terms('myevents', array('hide_empty' => '0'));      
    foreach ( $tax_terms as $tax_term ):
      $termSlug[] = $tax_term->slug;   
    endforeach;

//Assign the date into variable 

    $start_date = '01-May-2019';
    $end_date ='10-May-2019';  

//use the date format acccording to SQL format

    $start_date_new = date("YOUR DATE FORMAT", strtotime($start_date));
    $end_date_new = date("YOUR DATE FORMAT", strtotime($end_date));
    $event_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'Event',  //Post type event  
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query'=>array(    //Meta Query search
            'relation'=>'AND',
             array(
                'key' => 'start_date',
                'value' => $start_date_new, //start date here
                'compare' => '>=',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC'
             ),
             array(
                'key' => 'end_date',
                'value' => $end_date_new, //end date here
                'compare' => '<=',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC'
             )
         ),
        'tax_query' => array(
            array (
                'taxonomy' => 'myevents', //Taxonomy search 
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $termSlug,  //terms in array
            )
        ),
    );
    $all_events = new WP_Query($event_args); 

    echo '<pre>';print_r($all_events);echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: use this code on form action search.php template. You need to work with custom wordpress query for event custom post type on this page. You need to modify this code according to your requirement. 95% this code is correct. Only you need to modify this accordingly.

Comment: $start_date = '01-May-2019';  this date coming from input text... in php we use $_Post["Start"], but how to access them in php ? btw Thanks a lot for your support

Comment: $start_date will be come from input text $_POST['start_date'] and that will be dynamic. 
There are two options:
1) if you are using search.php default template for searching, then you have to use the above query in search.php by this code reference. 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
use the query with wordpress loop. 
2) if you are using this into any other template then you have to code into functions.php with init action. 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init
Use the wp_query in init action.